# Conversion of SSLContext from Java to Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp, sslcontext

I was trying to replicate this process of self-signed certificate process (link: https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-self-signed-cert) in an android app that is using Kotlin. The problem is the implementation in the link I've provided is in Java and I can't seem to correctly convert this code to its Kotlin version.

```
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { TRUST_ALL_CERTS }, new java.security.SecureRandom());
```

This is how I implemented it in Kotlin:

```
val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
.init(null, arrayOf(TRUST_ALL_CERTS) as Array<TrustManager>,
    java.security.SecureRandom()) as SSLContext
```

I casted the init to SSLContext because it is in Unit but after doing so, this warning appears:

> **this cast can never succeed**

What could be an alternative fix for this one? Theoretically, it will cause an error once I publish it, and I want to avoid it. Please help. Thank you

Note: I can't test my app on my local machine because the app communicates with a server that will not allow the app to be ran locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it atomically use apply

```
val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL").apply {
  init(null, arrayOf<TrustManager>(TRUST_ALL_CERTS), java.security.SecureRandom())
}
```

Comment: It's working now. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`SSLContext.init()` is returning `void` ( or `Unit` in Kotlin), so you are basically trying to cast `Unit` to `SSLContext`, which will never successed

You should seprate statements like this:

```kotlin
val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
sslContext.init(null, arrayOf(TRUST_ALL_CERTS) as Array<TrustManager>,
    java.security.SecureRandom())
```